# Bigquery insert a table into another one while using "with" to declare variables ahead

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to insert a dataset into another one and here is my snippet:

```
With questions AS (
SELECT * FROM 
`bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` A
JOIN
`bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.users` U
ON A.owner_user_id = U.id
),

POST_USER_TAG_INFO AS (
SELECT Q.*, t.* FROM
questions Q CROSS JOIN 
unnest(split(Q.tags, '|')) col join
bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.tags t
ON
col=t.tag_name
)

INSERT INTO inbound-summit-278521.datawarehousing_coursework.Dimensions (ID, post_id, user_id, tag_id, badge_id, location_id)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(), P.id, owner_user_id, P.id_2, b.id, location FROM
POST_USER_TAG_INFO P
JOIN
bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.badges b
ON P.owner_user_id = b.user_id
LIMIT 100;
```

It returns that there is a bug:

```
Syntax error: Expected "(" or "," or keyword SELECT but got keyword INSERT at [18:1]
```

**NOTE**: I am using Google Bigquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WITH` clause goes into the `SELECT` branch of the INSERT ...SELECT :

```sql
INSERT INTO inbound-summit-278521.datawarehousing_coursework.Dimensions (
  ID, post_id, user_id, tag_id, badge_id, location_id
)
WITH questions AS (
  SELECT * FROM 
  `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` A
  JOIN
  `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.users` U
  ON A.owner_user_id = U.id
),
POST_USER_TAG_INFO AS (
  SELECT Q.*, t.* FROM
  questions Q CROSS JOIN 
  unnest(split(Q.tags, '|')) col join
  bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.tags t
  ON
  col=t.tag_name
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(), P.id, owner_user_id, P.id_2, b.id, location FROM
POST_USER_TAG_INFO P
JOIN
bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.badges b
ON P.owner_user_id = b.user_id
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: Is it the only solution? The code is kind of redundant and I want a clean one.

Comment: Oh, yeah, you are right! This is a brilliant answer tho! I was busy earlier and failed to read it thoroughly! Thank you both!